# Tomcat authentification failed - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: windows, tomcat

I have an error when trying to access to Tomcat management console (Apache Tomcat/8.0.50).

> WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-7]
> org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.filterLockedAccounts An attempt
> was made to authenticate the locked user "admin"

I changed configuration file "tomcat-users.xml" and restarted tomcat

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<user username="admin" password="!w@B@#7XTFj" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui" />
```

Information about "realm" in server.xml

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
```

and about "Resources"

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
                     <Resource name="jdbc/ERS"
                        auth="Container"
                        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
                        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:port:BDD_name"
                        username="SAU_BIS"
                        password="V0t0,z91!"
                        maxActive="100000"
                        maxIdle="100000"  />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

I added loglvel : org.apache.catalina.realm.level = FINE and I have this information:

```
13-Mar-2020 08:19:08.515 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[JMX Proxy interface]' against GET /status --> false
13-Mar-2020 08:19:08.515 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Status interface]' against GET /status --> true
13-Mar-2020 08:19:08.515 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[HTML Manager interface (for humans)]' against GET /status --> false
13-Mar-2020 08:19:08.515 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Text Manager interface (for scripts)]' against GET /status --> false
13-Mar-2020 08:19:08.515 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[JMX Proxy interface]' against GET /status --> false
13-Mar-2020 08:19:08.515 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Status interface]' against GET /status --> true
13-Mar-2020 08:19:08.515 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[HTML Manager interface (for humans)]' against GET /status --> false
13-Mar-2020 08:19:08.515 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Text Manager interface (for scripts)]' against GET /status --> false
13-Mar-2020 08:19:08.515 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasUserDataPermission   User data constraint has no restrictions
13-Mar-2020 08:19:24.345 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[JMX Proxy interface]' against GET /status --> false
13-Mar-2020 08:19:24.345 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Status interface]' against GET /status --> true
13-Mar-2020 08:19:24.345 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[HTML Manager interface (for humans)]' against GET /status --> false
13-Mar-2020 08:19:24.345 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Text Manager interface (for scripts)]' against GET /status --> false
13-Mar-2020 08:19:24.345 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[JMX Proxy interface]' against GET /status --> false
13-Mar-2020 08:19:24.345 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Status interface]' against GET /status --> true
13-Mar-2020 08:19:24.345 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[HTML Manager interface (for humans)]' against GET /status --> false
13-Mar-2020 08:19:24.345 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Text Manager interface (for scripts)]' against GET /status --> false
13-Mar-2020 08:19:24.345 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasUserDataPermission   User data constraint has no restrictions
13-Mar-2020 08:19:24.361 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate Attempting to authenticate user "admin" with realm "org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
13-Mar-2020 08:19:24.361 FINE [http-apr-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate Failed to authenticate user "admin" with realm "org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
```

But it's still impossible to access on console.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Wait for 300 seconds and try again

Comment: wait 300 seconds after restart ?

Comment: This is the usual recommendation for locked user. Just try it :)

Comment: i changed configaration last week but it's still blocked.

Comment: Try to add another user with the same roles. ANd just for test select sample password, only letters and numbers

Comment: no, even with a new user, impossible to access :(

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the part of your `server.xml` which deals with authentication (notable the `<Realm>` and `<Resource>` files)? You can also increase the loglevel (`org.apache.catalina.realm.level = FINE` in `logging.properties`).

Comment: i can't increase loglevel for org.apache.catalina.realm.level because it's not defined in logging.properties

Comment: You just need to add a `org.apache.catalina.realm.level = FINE` line (cf. [Tomcat's logging](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html).

Comment: I added loglevel and i have this informations (added in my question)

Comment: Thanks for the log, unfortunately it doesn't give any useful information (it only says the password is wrong). You might dig deeper increasing the level of other loggers: cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12311496/11748454).

Answer (score 0):

It says username 'admin' was locked, change the username to anything else and restart the tomcat server.